# the image of a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic variety in $\mathbf{A}^n_k$ and $f\in A(X)$ be a non-constant morphism on $X$, how can we prove that $f(X)$ contains an open subset of $\mathbf{A}^1_k$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT 1:** The statement is not true if $X$ is of dimension zero. For example, then $X$ could be a finite subset of $\mathbb A^1$, and $f$ the restriction of the identity map.

**HINT 2:**

A non-constant morphism is the same as a non-constant map $f:X \to \mathbb A^1$.

Note that the closed subsets of $\mathbb A^1$ are just the finite ones. Then I claim that the image cannot be closed. Reason: every closed subset of $\mathbb A^1$ is disconnected.

Can you go from here?

**ADDED**

Since the closed sets in $\mathbb A^1$ are just the finite sets, then as soon as a subset of $\mathbb A^1$ contains an open, it is open. Because if $U \subset Z$ is open, then $\mathbb A^1 \backslash Z \subset \mathbb A^1 \backslash U$, and the last one is a finite set. So we just have to show that $f(X)$ is open, or equivalently, that $f$ misses just a finite set of values.

**COMMENT**

The statement is clearly not true without restrictions. For example if $k=\mathbb R$, let $X=\{y - x^2 = 0 \} \subset \mathbb A^2$ and let $f$ be projection to the $y$ axis. Then the image is just the positive values, but by the above comment, this set does not contain any open.

Comment: Yes. I know that $f(X)$ should be irreducible in $\mathbf{A}^1_k$. But why it contains an open subset, that is, $\mathbf{A}^1_k\backslash f(X)$ is a finite set?

Comment: @ Fredrik Meyer Thanks for your explanation. But I still don't get it. For example, let $k=\mathbb{C}$, then $\mathbb{R}$ is irreducible, but it does not contain any open subset. Am I ring?

Comment: @m-agag2016 Sorry, I deleted my last comment. It was false. You are right.

Comment: @m-agag2016 I've added some comments to my answer.

Comment: @ Fredrik Meyer If $k$ is algebraically closed, how to show that $f(X)$ is open in $\mathbf{A}^1_k$?